# client.DownloadFile() не закрывает файл

Tags: c#

я пытаюсь скачать файл с помощью client.DownloadFile(), однако что бы я не делал, данный файл не закрывается.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(link, $"tempImage.jpg");
    client.Dispose();
}
File.Delete("tempImage.jpg");//Ошибка: файл используется другим процессом
```

Использую .Net Core 3.1.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: А вы уверены, что его держит именно сишарп? Может, его в это время проверяет антивирус например?

Comment: По крайней мере, судя по исходникам, внутри DownloadFile файл [вполне закрывается](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v3.1.0/src/System.Net.WebClient/src/System/Net/WebClient.cs#L336)

Comment: Не работает именно показанный код или в промежутке между скачиванием и удалением файл как-то используется? В частности, класс `System.Drawing.Bitmap` удерживает хендл, из-за него у многих возникает такая проблема. / А вообще, `File.Delete` пользуется дурной славой. Если обязательно нужно удалить файл, то часто предлагают решения наподобие: в цикле пытаться это сделать, с паузой между попытками. Ещё рекомендуют сборку мусора произвести перед его вызовом: `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();` - угу, Collect два раза.

Comment: Используя ```using``` вы уже вызываете ```Dispose()``` по завершению конструкции. Не вызывайте ```client.Dispose()``` отдельно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebClient` является устаревшим классом

Используйте `HttpClient`, работает это примерно так:

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string link = "https://link";
    string path = "tempImage.jpg";
    await DownloadFileAsync(link, path);
    File.Delete(path);
}

static async Task DownloadFileAsync(string link, string path)
{
    using var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(link);
    using var fs = File.Create(path);
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
}
```

Что касается того что файл не закрывается, то этого по факту не может быть, так как судя по всем исходникам и логике, файл должен быть закрыт. В вашем коде из ненормального только лишний вызов `Dispose()`. То есть проблема за пределами показанного кода. Про антивирус в комментах вполне правдивая история.

Кстати, в .NET Core `WebClient` использует тот же `HttpClient` внутри себя.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблему решил, однако на счет старого метода: никаких антивирусов у меня нет (кроме того который на 10 Винде вшит), а этот код и отдельно не работает без других кусков. Хм, ради интереса попробую отключить антивирус (он включается после перезапуска) и заного попробовать первый метод

Comment: Еще потом попробую декомпилить библиотеку и проверить её на наличие File.close, мб у меня либо какая то корявая